# How do I take keyboard input without a while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, keyboard, keyboard-events

I know how to get key input directly with the `keyboard` module but it needs a while loop around it specifically. if I use this in my code obviously it stops it in its tracks!

```py
while True:
    event = keyboard.read_event()
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        print(event.name)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a keyboard.listener in a non-blocking fashion (not in a `with` statement), as per the [documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard):

```py
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

# execution immediately continues past listener.start()
```

> When using the non-blocking version above, the current thread will continue executing. This might be necessary when integrating with other GUI frameworks that incorporate a main-loop, but when run from a script, this will cause the program to terminate immediately.